# Преобразование массива чисел и массив символов

Tags: массивы, char

Только учу программирование. Написала код, он работает, но я не могу понять, зачем для того, чтоб перевести int arr  в char надо писать только так:
`number [i] = '0' + arr[i];`

P.s `const int arr [10];  char number [10];`

Просто `number [i] = arr[i];` не работает. Что это за `'0' +` и для чего он нужен?

Comment: Вы бы язык уточнили в тегах...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Почему нельзя написать `number [i] = arr[i]`?**  Потому что `number[i]` имеет тип данных `char`, а `arr[i]` - тип `int`. Они по-разному хранятся в памяти компьютера, занимают разное число байт. Поэтому для начала необходимо привести один тип данных к другому.

**2. Что это за '0' + и для чего он нужен?** В данном случае вам необходимо уметь из числа 0 делать символ '0', из числа 1 делать символ '1'? ..., из числа 9 делать символ '9'. Это можно сделать различными способами. Один из них - воспользоваться тем, что [у каждого символа есть свой код](https://unicode-table.com/ru/). Так, например, [символ '0' имеет код 30](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#0030), а [символ '9' имеет код 39](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#0039). Можно заметить, что символы цифр в таблице идут подряд - так же как и сами цифры. Этим можно воспользоваться и сказать, что симол '5' имеет код на 5 больше, чем у символа '0'. Таким образом, получаем формулу для цифр от 0 до 9: `'n' = '0' + n`. А если вернуться к вашему примеру, то это как раз `number[i] = '0' + arr[i]`.